# How to delete lines matching a certain pattern in Perl?

Tags: perl

I'd like to do something similar to `sed` in Perl, namely be able to delete lines matching a certain pattern.

Given this input:

```
abcd
edfd
abcd
derder
abcd
erre
```

I want to remove the lines containing `bc`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to use double quotes on Windows:

```
perl -ne "print unless /bc/" file
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a FAQ.

[How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f)

If you're programming in Perl then it's well worth taking a couple of hours to familiarise yourself with the [FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq.html).