# How can I parse a report and generate a summary of different conditions?

Tags: perl

I want to delete specific lines from a file.

The results I want are:

```
The Nodes that Running are: ls_sfda-new,risto4,
The Nodes that isnt Running are: atum1,
The Nodes that Buffering are: vmatum3,
The Nodes that Cannot get status are: vcmobile,
```

My text (contains about 60 nodes):

```
Node atum1:
HPOM Managed Node status :
-------------------------
OV Performance Core       coda        (3568) isnt running
OV Communication Broker   ovbbccb     (2348) is running
OV Control                ovcd        (2088) is running
OV Config and Deploy      ovconfd     (2516) is running
Subagent EA:
Action Agent              opcacta     (3372) is running
Logfile Encapsulator      opcle       (3788) is running
Monitor Agent             opcmona     (3668) is running
Message Agent             opcmsga     (3456) is running
Message Interceptor       opcmsgi     (3600) isnt running
Done.

Node vmatum3:
HPOM Managed Node status :
-------------------------
OV Performance Core       coda        (3128) is running(buffering)
OV Communication Broker   ovbbccb     (2112) is running
OV Control                ovcd        (444) is running
OV Config and Deploy      ovconfd     (2336) is running
Subagent EA:
Action Agent              opcacta     (3088) is running
Logfile Encapsulator      opcle       (3180) is running
Monitor Agent             opcmona     (3424) is running
Message Agent             opcmsga     (3236) is running
Message Interceptor       opcmsgi     (3348) is running
Done.

Node ls_sfda-new:
HPOM Managed Node status :
-------------------------
OV Control                ovcd        (2236) is running
OV Performance Core       coda        (3132) is running
OV Communication Broker   ovbbccb     (2780) is running
OV Config and Deploy      ovconfd     (3156) is running
Subagent EA:
Action Agent              opcacta     (256) is running
Logfile Encapsulator      opcle       (300) is running
Monitor Agent             opcmona     (392) is running
Message Agent             opcmsga     (400) is running
Message Interceptor       opcmsgi     (960) is running
Done.

Node risto4:
HPOM Managed Node status :
-------------------------
OV Performance Core       coda        (3348) is running
OV Communication Broker   ovbbccb     (1848) is running
OV Control                ovcd        (2276) is running
OV Config and Deploy      ovconfd     (4664) is running
Subagent EA:
Action Agent              opcacta     (4872) is running
Logfile Encapsulator      opcle       (2912) is running
Monitor Agent             opcmona     (2224) is running
Message Agent             opcmsga     (2392) is running
Message Interceptor       opcmsgi     (3436) is running
Done.

Node vcmobile:
Cannot get status information from node vcmobile.  (OpC40-428)
Network communication problems occurred. (OpC40-427)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CTRL - CommunicationException:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(ctrl-21) Communication error when executing 'Status' method.
 (xpl-333) recv() on '[10.24.33.40]:383' failed.
  (RTL-104) Connection reset by peer (OpC40-2130)
Failed.
```

My code (I know I need an `elsif` loop but I need some help):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

open (FILE, "/tmp/agentstas.dat");
my @lines = <FILE>;
my $lines;
my $string = "Node";
my $badstring = "hpom";
my $buffering = "buffering";
my $Running = "Running";
my $isnt = "isnt";
my $Cannot = "Cannot";

foreach $lines (@lines) {
    if ($lines =~ /^$string/i || $lines !~ /^$badstring/i) { 
        print "$lines";
    }
```

Comment: Please format your post.

Comment: Add `use warnings`. Check the return value from `open()`. Use a lexical filehandle and the three-argument version of `open()`. Oh, and it's a good idea to show us code that, at least, compiles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete lines matching a certain pattern in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421100/how-to-delete-lines-matching-a-certain-pattern-in-perl)

Comment: Try asking a question.

Comment: @tripleee It's not a dup of that post because the title of this question is misleading. The title of this question should be something more along the lines of "How can I parse a report and generate a summary of different conditions?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need help to write PERL program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973652/i-need-help-to-write-perl-program)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier than you think with `$/` - the record seperator. Set it to a double line feed, and then you can match records, not individual lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

local $/ = "\n\n";

open ( my $input, '<', '/tmp/agentstas.dat') or die $!;
while ( <$input> ) {
    my ($name) = m/Node (\w+)/; 
    my %proc_state = m/(\w+)\s+\(\d+\) (.*)/g; 
    print Dumper \%proc_state; 

    if ( m/isnt running/ ) { 
          print "$name not running\n"; 
    }

    if ( m/buffering/ ) { 
         print "$name buffering\n";
    }

    if ( m/Cannot get status information/ ) {
         print "$name no status information\n"
    }

    if ( defined $name and not keys %proc_state ) { 
        print "No process states from $name\n"; 
    }
}
close ( $input );
```

Comment: Hello Sobeique, when i try to run the script its says :Name "main::Dumper" used only once: possible typo at k.pl line 11.
print() on unopened filehandle Dumper at k.pl line 11, <$input> chunk 1.
print() on unopened filehandle Dumper at k.pl line 11, <$input> chunk 2.
print() on unopened filehandle Dumper at k.pl line 11, <$input> chunk 3.

Comment: thats print:$VAR1 = {
          'ovbbccb' => 'is running',
          'coda' => 'is running',
          'ovconfd' => 'is running',
          'opcmona' => 'is running',
          'opcle' => 'is running',
          'opcacta' => 'is running',
          'ovcd' => 'is running',
          'opcmsga' => 'is running',
          'opcmsgi' => 'is running'
        };
$VAR1 = {
         'ovbbccb' => 'is running',
         'opcacta' => 'is running',
         'ovcd' => 'is running',
          'opcmsga' => 'is running',
          'opcmsgi' => 'is running'
        };
and i want it like results  please help me.

Comment: You missed a ; then but that's how to gather the data.  Format it as you wish.